# Simulating Facebook videos embedding behaviors in Drupal?

Tags: javascript, social-network

If users are posting comments to a Drupal site and the comment contains a link to a video on YouTube or other sites, I would like to see similar behavior to that when posting a link to a video on Facebook. That is, once the link is entered, it triggers the embedding mechanism and generates a preview in edit mode.

Answer (score 1):

The [emfield](http://drupal.org/project/emfield) module does that. It's D6 only at the moment.